# Ruby: How to run tasks in parallel in the simplest possible way

Tags: ruby

I'm looking for the simplest possible way to use it handy for system administration in general.

I checked parallel/forkmanager, grosser/parallel, etc. but all seem to be not that simple to grasp.

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

servers = [ 'server1.example.com', 'server2.example.com', 'server3.example.com' ]

cmd = 'iostat 1 10'

servers.each do |server|
  puts server
  system("sshpass -f mypwfile ssh #{server} #{cmd}")
end
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use `Thread.new`?

Comment: `grosser/parallel` is super-easy. What specific problem do you have with it? You could literally just change `servers.each` with `Parallel.each(servers)` for the basic functionality. For the problem you had below (server overwhelmed), you can add `in_threads: 5` or `in_processes: 5` parameter to limit the number of agents.

Comment: Thanks for your encouraging and helpful words, Amadan! I'll have a second look and give it a try.

Comment: Excellent. It's rather much simpler than I thought, as you said, and working very nicely. Thanks so much, Amadan!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
servers = [ 'server1.example.com', 'server2.example.com', 'server3.example.com' ]

cmd = 'iostat 1 10'

servers.map do |server|
  Thread.new do
    puts server
    system("sshpass -f mypwfile ssh #{server} #{cmd}")
  end
end.each(&:join)
```

You need to call `join` on every thread otherwise they will be killed when the processes main thread exists.

Comment: Excellent,. Thanks, Kris! Is it also possible to serialize the output so that I can log all outputs in sequence, server by server?

Comment: Well, just used Thread to launch an ssh job to 100 servers and it made my hosting server sick and I had to reboot it. :)